# File local variables doesn't work

Tags: doom, file-local-variables

I tried putting a local file variable in an org mode file:

```
# -*- mode:org; coding:utf-8; org-duration-format: h:mm; -*-
```

but when I open this file the variable has the original value and not the one I set. Also `file-local-variables-alist` is `nil`.

I tried with only:`# -*- org-duration-format: h:mm; -*-`, with another variables and also with a plain text file, but never the file local variables made any effect.

The value of `enable-local-variables` is `:safe`, as default.

Comment: Is that the very first line in the file? No empty (or other) lines before it. The only time when it is allowed to be the *second* line in the file is when the first line is a shebang line (`#! /bin/bash` or similar).

Comment: Yes it is the very first line

Comment: Have you tried setting `enable-local-variables` to `t`?

Comment: mhm with `enable-local-variables` as `t` it complains that `org-duration-format` is not safe, so indeed this has to be the problem. I thought it was a safe variable.

Comment: By the way is there a way to know which variables are safe by default? I know of `safe-local-varaible-values` to add safe variables but I cannot find a list of safe variables by default.

Comment: Do `C-h i g (elisp) File Local Variables`. Basically, a variable that has a `safe-local-variable` property is safe. E.g. `(get 'fill-column 'safe-local-variable)` returns `integerp` - a predicate which can test for legal values.

Comment: Thank you so much! In facts `(get 'org-duration-format 'safe-local-variable)` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by @NickD, `org-duration-format` isn't a safe variable:

```lisp
(get 'org-duration-format 'safe-local-variable) ; nil
```

So there are two ways:

1. Set `enable-local-variables` to `t` for getting asked if to trust that variable when the file is opened:

```lisp
(setq enable-local-variables t)
```

2. Push `org-duration-format` into `safe-local-variable-values`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'safe-local-variable-values '(org-duration-format . h:mm))
```

Comment: Or you can set `enable-local-variables` to `t` and when you are asked, then type `!` which does the equivalent of your way #2 and saves the result in your custom file, so that it is remembered for the future - note that only the combination of `(variable, value)` that you set is remembered: if you change the value then it's going to ask you again. Once you have done that, then you can set `enable-local-variables` to `:safe` but if you try with a different variable that has not been saved, you are back at the beginning and you'll have to do the whole thing again for the new variable.

Comment: Or you can add a `safe-local-variable` property to the variable with a predicate to check the legality of the value, the way emacs does it for the common safe variables - see the function `safe-local-variable-p` in `files.el` for how emacs determines whether a variable is safe.